# function that generates a vector of values beta from X and y in r

Tags: r

I would like to write a function that generates a vector of values of beta from X and y, we get

beta = [(X^T)*X]^-1 * (X^T) * y

I Wrote a code as this, but it turns error as
Error in t(X) * X : non-conformable arrays

please help me with this.

code:

```
set.seed(143)
X <- cbind(rep(1,50), rnorm(50,0,1), rnorm(50,0,1))
y <- 3 + -4*X[,2] + 2*X[,3] + rnorm(50,0,1)

BetaEstimator <- function(X, y){
Beta <- solve(t(X)*X) * t(X) * y
  return(Beta)}
BetaEstimator(X,y)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the notation for matrix multiplication, that is, use `%*%` instead of `*`.

Try:

```
BetaEstimator <- function(X, y) {
  solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) * y
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use matrix product `%*%`, rather than element-wise product `*`. Also, `crossprod` can be used to simplify your expression, like below

```
BetaEstimator <- function(X, y) {
  solve(crossprod(X)) %*% crossprod(X, y)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using the QR decomposition.

```
BetaEstimator <- function(X, y) solve.qr(qr(X), y)

set.seed(143)
X <- cbind(rep(1,50), rnorm(50,0,1), rnorm(50,0,1))
y <- 3 + -4*X[,2] + 2*X[,3] + rnorm(50,0,1)

# compare with R's linear model    
fit <- lm.fit(X, y)

coef(fit)
#       x1        x2        x3 
# 3.101107 -3.976275  1.966437 

BetaEstimator(X, y)
#[1]  3.101107 -3.976275  1.966437
```

The coefficients are equal to R's.